# How can I copy and paste widgets in Workshop?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

I have a workshop with a complex button widget that I want in multiple different places in the app. Is there a way to quickly copy this widget into multiple places without going through the time-consuming process of creating it anew every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy and paste widgets using ctrl + c, and then select ctrl + v anywhere in the document. They will then appear in the "unused widgets" area in the lower left hand side of the layout panel.
[image: Unused Widget Bar]
You can add these unused widgets back into your workshop by adding a widget and searching for its name.
[image: Add Unused widget]